# Angular 6 http.delete request not working

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

I cant seem to get my delete request to work. I have finished all of the get requests but now I'm stuck on delete and can't seem to wrap my head around it.

The console.log'd URL is always correct and the delete request works fine via Postman.

Got any ideas?

HTML

```
<button class="button button3" (click)="delTicket()"><span class="fa fa-trash"></span></button>
```

TS

```
delTicket(){
    this.id = this.route.snapshot.params.id;
    this.ticketService.deleteTicket(this.id);
}
```

Service

```
deleteTicket(id): Observable<Ticket[]>{
    console.log(this.apiUrl + id);
    return this.http.delete<Ticket[]>(this.apiUrl + id);
}
```

Comment: Any errors in the console?

Comment: None, just logs the URL.

Comment: what abt network tab in dev tool? are u able to del it after the API ia called and page is refreshed? ?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You need to call **subscribe()** inside your component, otherwise request wont get invoked

```
delTicket(){
    this.id = this.route.snapshot.params.id;
    this.ticketService.deleteTicket(this.id).subscribe((data)=>{
         console.log("success");
    });
}
```

Comment: In 3 minutes :D

Answer (score 5):

You must call **subscribe()** or nothing happens. Just calling ticketService.deleteTicket(this.id) does not initiate the DELETE request.

1. An HttpClient method does not begin its HTTP request until you call subscribe() on the observable returned by that method. This is true for all HttpClient methods.
2. Calling subscribe(...) triggers execution of the observable and causes HttpClient to compose and send the HTTP request to the server.

Comment: Dude this was september 2018 :D

Comment: @HeikoPiirme Doesn't matter . addtional explaination is always good :)